# push element into an array in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and I have following array:

```
$data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('uname'),
                'fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
                'lname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
                'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'password' => $this->input->post('pass'),
                'bdate' => $this->input->post('date'),
                'status' => $this->input->post('status')

            );
```

I want to push following item in that

```
$data = array_push($data, 'userfile', $_FILES['userfile']['name']);
```

Please make correction in it.
How to push an element in to an array.

Answer (score 4):

Just do this

```
$data['userfile']=$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
```

Comment: above solution should work. have you check that you got $_FILES data properly just try var_dump($_FILES) 
and in your form has this attr enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: i think i have to use array_push().
but i don't know how to use it??